# How to generate barcode fast

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, parallel-processing

```
if File.directory?("#{Rails.root}/public/barcodes") == false
  system 'mkdir', '-p', "#{Rails.root}/public/barcodes"
end

Parallel.each((1000000000001..1000000001000).to_a, in_processes: 10) do |barcode_number|
  barcode = Barby::Code128B.new(barcode_number)
  File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/barcodes/#{barcode_number}.png", 'wb'){ |f|
    f.write barcode.to_png(height: 50, xdim: 2, margin: 2)
  }

  Barcode.create(member_id: barcode_number.to_s, barcode_image: File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/barcodes/#{barcode_number}.png"))
end

FileUtils.rm_f Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/public/barcodes/*")
```

Above is my code that generate barcode and store into AWS S3 server.

The functionality is working fine as per the my requirement.
If I generate 1000 barcodes then it will take 60 to 70 Sec.

Now, I want to optimize the time, I want to store 1000 barcodes with in less then 20 sec. So How can I do this?

Comment: Perhaps a faster internet connection with a smaller latency to Amazon?

Comment: What's the bottleneck?

Comment: I'm willing to bet that calling `Barcode.create` 1,000 times is taking up a lot more time than generating the barcodes. Here's a thought: Don't generate 1,000 images up-front. Wait for a particular Barcode to be requested and create and store its image at that time. That first request will consequently be a bit slower, but you only have to do it once.